# Is there a workaround for using @RunWith in JUnit?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit

I've one main test class (A) and another (B) that extends from it.

A has a `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` annotation to initialize it.
I need to use `@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)` annotation on B.

But it seems like I won't be able to do both. Is there a way I can have parameterized test suites without the `@RunWith` annotation?

The other solution is to use

```
testContextManager = new TestContextManager(AbstractInvoiceCreationModuleTest.class);
testContextManager.prepareTestInstance(this);
```

But I can not write this within the `@BeforeClass` method as it is static and doesn't allow using of this. I do not wish to write the above piece of code within the `@Before` method as the class will get initialized before every test method. And a lot of test classes extend from A.

What can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a rule instead of the `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class`: http://www.alexecollins.com/tutorial-junit-rule/

Comment: The link was quite useful, Thank you!

Comment: Just my 2c, initialising Spring application context before every test method (as seen in the blog post) is not very efficient and will significantly decrease performance of the tests. The test context should be cached (somehow). E.g. spring-test framework inits the context only once and it's shared for all the tests.

Answer (score 2):

Spring added support for @Rule based JUnit support for the Spring Context in version 4.2.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#testcontext-junit4-rules

Example from that documentation:

```
// Optionally specify a non-Spring Runner via @RunWith(...)
@ContextConfiguration
public class IntegrationTest {

   @ClassRule
   public static final SpringClassRule SPRING_CLASS_RULE = new SpringClassRule();

   @Rule
   public final SpringMethodRule springMethodRule = new SpringMethodRule();

   @Test
   public void testMethod() {
      // execute test logic...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about that specific case (Spring test runners), but I had a similar case and ended up creating my own runner.

Comment: I don't wish to write a runner. That defeats the purpose of using parameterized testing, I'll have to write logic, which has the potential to introduces bugs.

Comment: What I propose is extending SpringJunit4ClassRunner to SpringJunit4ParamRunner (or reverse). You obviously don't want to create a runner with logic specific to your test. They are painful to write though, so only worth it if you have many tests with the same pattern.